# Freezing the DOM to JavaScript: Overwriting DOM modification functions as no-ops

Tags: javascript, dom, sandbox

I'm writing a piece of code that requires the `DOM` of a website to remain frozen while arbitrary JavaScript runs. Attributes changing is fine but I can't have anything changing the original tag structure of the page!

I know in JavaScript there are a base number of functions that can modify the `DOM`:

```
appendChild( nodeToAppend )
cloneNode( true|false )
createElement( tagName )
createElemeentNS( namespace, tagName )
createTextNode( textString )
innerHTML
insertBefore( nodeToInsert, nodeToInsertBefore )
removeChild( nodetoRemove )
replacechild( nodeToInsert, nodeToReplace )
```

My initial thought was simply to overwrite these functions as no ops:

```
>>> document.write('<p>Changing your DOM. Mwwhaha!</p>')
>>> document.write = function() {}
>>> document.write('<p>No-op now!</p>')
```

While it's easy to do this for the `document` object the `DOM` modification functions can be called from many different JavaScript objects! If I could overwrite these functions at top level perhaps it would work?

Update from sktrdie:

```
>>> HTMLElement.prototype.appendChild = function(){}
>>> $("a").get(0).appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
# Still works argh.
>>> HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.appendChild = function(){}
>>> $("a").get(0).appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
# No-op yeah!
```

So it would seem I could just gather the constructors of all `DOM` elements and run over them putting in no-ops but that still seems pretty messy ...

**How can I protect the `DOM` from modification from arbitrary JavaScript?**

Comment: Wow. What are you doing this for? Really curious.

Comment: I've got an iFrame that proxies in a webpage showing the site. You then pick bits of the site using JavaScript I inject - I'm grabbing CSS selectors off what you pick. So the `DOM` needs to stay the same or the selectors will break (but other JavaScript should run as normal!)

Comment: So specifically you want to stop the javascript that is loaded in the *child* iframe from modifying the DOM?

Comment: I don't think the fact that i'm using it in an iFrame effects the question.

I want to stop the iFrame from modifying it's own DOM - I'm not worried about it attacking parent window DOM.

Comment: You are right. Just clarifying.

What if the child page modifies its DOM as part of the user experience and you go blasting that away?

Comment: Well that's too bad then :) - certainly this technique is going to result in errors as j/s which expects those functions to behave in certain ways is going to be surprised - but before I was stripping out _all_ JavaScript to protect the DOM - so this is an improvement on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried **HTMLElement**.prototype.appendChild = function(){} to overwrite DOM methods at a higher level?

Comment: This is close. The problem is HTMLDivElement / HTMLAnchorElement etc. will not be effected by this ...

Comment: I don't think IE has this built into their DOM. Maybe the later versions but I remember IE6 not having it.

Answer (score 1):

While this is really hackish, the only way to maintain the current DOM structure is to store a "snapshot" of the DOM and check it periodically.

```
//place in anonymous function to prevent global access
(function() {
  //storing the whole DOM as objects would be ideal, but too memory intensive, so a string will have to do.
  var originalDOM = document.body.innerHTML;

  var checkDOM = function() {
    if (document.body.innerHTML != originalDOM)  document.body.innerHTML = originalDOM
    //check that the code is running
    if (arbitraryCodeIsRunning)  setTimeout("checkDOM", 100);
  }
  checkDOM();
})();
```

Probably not what your looking for, but after some testing it's the only way I can think of to maintain DOM structure regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Use a whitelist. Please.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly put everything in a `<div>` tag, and hide that tag, replacing it with another that says 'Loading..'. Then after it has loaded you could hide the loading `<div>` and replace it with the original.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. I did a couple of tests and no matter how I tried to overwrite these methods they remain. I believe that they are implemented in a higher level than executable javascript can access, so you can't really touch them.